# Django pass environment value to Logstash

Tags: django

Joined a project in which there is already a written logger. It is necessary to add the transfer of the environment value before any message of the logger for the convenience of filtering.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzioI.png)

[Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmsmv.png)

How i can do this?

Settings:

```
APP_ENV = os.getenv("APP_ENV")

LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'graypy': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'graypy.GELFHandler',
        'host': 'logstash...',
        'port': 12222,
    },
    'console': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['graypy', 'console'],
        'level': 'WARNING'
    },
    'mts_marketplace': {
        'handlers': ['graypy', 'console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'mts_marketplace.processing': {
        'handlers': ['graypy', 'console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'mts_marketplace.internal_api': {
        'handlers': ['graypy', 'console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'mts_marketplace.trustedgoods': {
        'handlers': ['graypy', 'console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'mts_marketplace.fka': {
        'handlers': ['graypy', 'console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': False,
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow allows you to include images in your question. Linked images make the question far less readable.

Comment: Need a reputation more than 15.

Comment: do you mean that you need a JSON object in the log output instead of a string?

Comment: Use a [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#filters) to modify your logging record prior to being emitted. There you can check your `settings` for example to determine the environment and add it as a variable to the logger so you can use it in the formatter.

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: @Risadinha, i want to add parametr `environment`

Comment: @dirkgroten, I have a defined environment, but I don’t know how to substitute into the formatter ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django uses Python's logging mechanism, so this part is also working for Django:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-loggeradapters-to-impart-contextual-information

> Using LoggerAdapters to impart contextual information
>
> An easy way in which you can pass contextual information to be output
>   along with logging event information is to use the LoggerAdapter
>   class. This class is designed to look like a Logger, so that you can
>   call debug(), info(), warning(), error(), exception(), critical() and
>   log(). These methods have the same signatures as their counterparts in
>   Logger, so you can use the two types of instances interchangeably.

or, as @dirkgroten already suggested:

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information

> Using Filters to impart contextual information
>
> You can also add contextual information to log output using a
>   user-defined Filter. Filter instances are allowed to modify the
>   LogRecords passed to them, including adding additional attributes
>   which can then be output using a suitable format string, or if needed
>   a custom Formatter.

Both sections provide example code.